# When MongoDB aggregate can't find any result, it returns an array with an empty object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get the list of my single project's bids within the project's aggregate.

but when I run my Mongodb aggregate, if it can't find any result for bids of the project, it returns this result:

```
[ { _id: 5b69f6afa1ad1827cc9e1dc6,
    projectID: 100029,
    bidsArray: [ { freelanceArray: {} } ]
} ]
```

But I want to return empty **bidsArray** if it can't find related bids, (something like this):

```
[ { _id: 5b69f6afa1ad1827cc9e1dc6,
    projectID: 100029,
    bidsArray: []
} ]
```

Here is my aggregate:

```
[
        {
            $match: {
                projectID: projectID
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "bids",
                localField: "projectID",
                foreignField: "projectID",
                as: "bidsArray"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$bidsArray",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "bidsArray.freelanceID",
                foreignField: "userID",
                as: "freelanceArray"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$freelanceArray",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                projectID: { $first: "$projectID" },
                bidsArray: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        bidID: "$bidsArray.bidID",
                        daysToDone: "$bidsArray.daysToDone",
                        freelanceArray: {
                            userID: "$freelanceArray.userID",
                            username: "$freelanceArray.username",
                            publicName: "$freelanceArray.publicName",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                projectID: 1,
                bidsArray: {
                    bidID: 1,
                    daysToDone: 1,
                    freelanceArray: {
                        userID: 1,
                        username: 1,
                        publicName: 1,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: try remove the project stage

Comment: @AmitWagner same result returned! :(

Comment: try remove preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true

Comment: then it returns this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bidsArray' of undefined

Comment: You can try below stage at the end `{
    $addFields: {
      bidsArray: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$bidsArray.freelanceArray.userId",
                  0
                ]
              },
              undefined
            ]
          },
          [],
          "$bidsArray"
        ]
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.6, you can use the variable [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) in aggregation expressions to conditionally suppress a field.

Remove the last [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage and update the freelanceArray expression inside [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as below. The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expression basically checks freelanceArray value when present ( not null value) output the fields else remove the freelanceArray.

```
"freelanceArray":{
  "$cond":[
    {"$gt":["$freelanceArray",0]},
    {"userID":"$freelanceArray.userID","username":"$freelanceArray.username","publicName":"$freelanceArray.publicName"},
    "$$REMOVE"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is solved my problem in 'freelanceArray' but, how I can add the same action for 'bidsArray' considering the $addToSet?